# Is there a way to use dotnet watch with docker compose, or something similar?

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, workflow

When developing with .NET Core we can use the `dotnet watch` tool in order to automaticaly recompile if anything changes.

On the other hand, Docker compose is really nice in order to bring together the .NET app, the database, any kind of messaging components, front end, and so forth at development time.

It turns out that in that case, there is one drawback. If I modify something on the .NET app, I need to stop Docker compose, and start again asking to rebuild the container. This is not something terrible, but it could be better.

Is there some way to use dotnet watch with Docker compose, or something similar?

In that case, I believe I would end up with two compose files: one for development and one for production. Is that correct? What is the right approach and workflow here?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to do this... once the dotnet watch is finished with recompiling the changes you can push the changes on to the running container possibly through a mount path and then you can use

> docker commit

to commit the container as a image with a new tag . This will save you the overhead of re-building the container . More info on docker commit can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#usage)